# If you commit a crime your punishment is premature aging

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember seeing a movie back when I was a kid that revolved around the idea of a punishment that revolved around "age payment."  If you committed a horrendous crime, rather than lock you up, they put you in a machine and age you 50+ years.

One of the main characters in the movie gets framed as a child for a crime, and he is then aged to about 40ish.  The movie deals with the concept of this type of punishment, as well as his ability to cope with the adult world with the mind of a child.  The idea was pretty interesting, but I do remember it being a "B" type of movie.

If I was to narrow it down, it would be late 80's early 90's.

Answer (score 9):

The plot of [Nightworld: 30 Years to Life](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0174446/) from 1998 sounds very much like it:

> In the near future, instead of being sent to prison criminals are aged for the number of years the system feels is adequate to the crime they committed. Vincent Dawson is a 15 year old, whose late father was a musician who didn't exactly make it and died tragically. Vinnie hopes to be a musician too but his step-father is not very supportive, and when they have a violent argument, his step-father is killed and he is the prime suspect and evidence is found against him. He is sentenced to be aged 30 years. Now, as a 15 year old trapped in a 45 year old body, he sets to prove his innocence and hopefully the procedure could be reversed.

[image]

Comment: @5StringRyan was this it?

Answer (score 2):

[Zardoz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070948/) -- From [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Zardoz):

> The immortals punish the criminal by speed-aging the offender. The more you resist, the closer you get to endless senility...

Comment: This is definitely not it.  This movie didn't have any big actors, not to mention the plot regarding the child aged is NOT in the plot for this movie at all.

Comment: Sorry.  I haven't seen the movie in 20+ years and only recalled the accelerated aging component.